# How to show or hide a table when hitting enter or clicking on search button

Tags: html, jquery

I have two tables in my html code and I would like to hide the table from my html page until I click enter in the search area or click on the search button. Once I click enter or hit enter on the search bar then I want my tables to appear.  Right now I am unable to get it to work from the examples I have seen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //To hide the table
  $("search-input").click(function() {
    $("table1").hide("fast")
  });
  //To show the table
  $("search-input").click(function() {
    $("table1").show("2000")
  });
  //To hide the table
  $("search-input").click(function() {
    $("table2").hide("fast")
  });
  //To show the table
  $("search-input").click(function() {
    $("table2").show("2000")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Search Bar-->
<div class="mb-1">
  <div class="container justify-content-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group mb-4"><input type="text" id="search-input" class="form-control input-text" placeholder="Enter Target Property: Street Address, City/Town, State" aria-label="Recipient's Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <span id="clickable-search-span">
                         <div class="input-group-append"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> </div>
    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comm-area">
    <div id="loader-area"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Search Bar End-->
!--Report Table Start -->
<div class="mb-2">
  <div class="results-section">
    <div class="report-wrapper">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-light" id="table1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="report-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Report</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Address: </th>
              <td id="proposed-address"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Latitude: </th>
              <td id="proposed-lat"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Longitude: </th>
              <td id="proposed-lng"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Rank: </th>
              <td id="proposed-rank"> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th> Description: </th>
              <td id="proposed-description"> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th> NHDES OneStop Website: </th>
              <td id="proposed-website"> </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Report Table End -->
<!-- Generator Sites Start-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="generator-wrapper text-center">
      <div class="generator-list">
        <table id="generator-table">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-light table-striped" id="table2">
              <tr>
                <th class="generator-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Generator Sites</th>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Distance (Miles) </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Distance (Feet) </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 2)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Generator Name </th>
                <th> Generator Address </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 4)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Generator Type(s) </th>
              </tr>
              <tbody id="generator-body">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Generator Sites Table End -->
```

Comment: None of your selectors has the appropriate syntax. Classes should be prefixed with periods and IDs with hash symbols.

Comment: Also, your snippet should be a minimal example just showing the problem, not the entire page with all the unrelated stuff. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (pure JavaScript, no jQuery). You will also need to add an HTML ID to the button (Here it is searchbutton)

```js
document.getElementById("table1").style.display = ''; // Show table
document.getElementById("search-input").onkeydown = function(event){ // Handle Textbox KeyDown Events
if (event.key == 'Enter'){ // If key is Enter.
document.getElementById("table1").style.display = 'none'; // Hide Table
}
}
document.getElementById("searchbutton").onclick = function(){ // On Button Click, show table.
document.getElementById("table1").style.display = 'none'; // Hide Table
}
```

Comment: Hi greatusername,  Your code is doing the opposite it is showing the table then hiding it once I enter info into the search box or click enter then it hides the table. I need to revers it so it hide the table then show the table after I click enter or click the show button.

Comment: I just reversed it, now try.

Comment: still doesn't work  it won't hide the table  I will play around with it and let you know.

Comment: Did you change the id of the button?

Comment: Yes I did   I added the id for the button  <div class="input-group-append"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search" id="searchbutton"></i></button> </div>

Comment: Add the id on `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">` instead of `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`. Example: `<div class="input-group-append"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="searchbutton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> </div>`

Comment: Didn't work  I am going to play around and see if I can get the table just to hide since that seems to be the issue.  I will let you know what I come up with

Comment: found a solution added style="display:none id="table1" to my html code Thanks for your help greatusername

Comment: Yes, `document.getElementById("table1").style.display = 'none'` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This code hides table1 onload.

When search-input is clicked, the view of table1 and table2 is toggled.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table1" ).hide();
    $("#search-input").click(function ()  {
        $("#table1" ).toggle();
        $("#table2" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: You should revise to add some explanation of your changes. Don't make us compare line by line to figure out what you did.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that's what you wanted.

```js
function showTables() {
  $("#table1").prop('hidden', false);
  $("#table2").prop('hidden', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Search Bar-->
<div class="mb-1">
  <div class="container justify-content-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group mb-4"><input type="text" id="search-input" class="form-control input-text" placeholder="Enter Target Property: Street Address, City/Town, State" aria-label="Recipient's Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <span id="clickable-search-span">
                         <div class="input-group-append"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" onclick="showTables()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> </div>
    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comm-area">
    <div id="loader-area"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Search Bar End-->
!--Report Table Start -->
<div class="mb-2">
  <div class="results-section">
    <div class="report-wrapper">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-light" id="table1" hidden>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="report-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Report</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Address: </th>
              <td id="proposed-address"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Latitude: </th>
              <td id="proposed-lat"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Longitude: </th>
              <td id="proposed-lng"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Rank: </th>
              <td id="proposed-rank"> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th> Description: </th>
              <td id="proposed-description"> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th> NHDES OneStop Website: </th>
              <td id="proposed-website"> </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Report Table End -->
<!-- Generator Sites Start-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="generator-wrapper text-center">
      <div class="generator-list">
        <table id="generator-table">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-light table-striped" id="table2" hidden>
              <tr>
                <th class="generator-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Generator Sites</th>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Distance (Miles) </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Distance (Feet) </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 2)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Generator Name </th>
                <th> Generator Address </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable('generator-table', 4)" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i> Generator Type(s) </th>
              </tr>
              <tbody id="generator-body">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Generator Sites Table End -->
```